# Google Protocol Buffers in C++: Creating a message from an existing struct

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm considering Google [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as a solution to my problem of communication between C++ and C# using named pipes. But I have one concern: all I've been able to find on protobuf is how to create a message from a prototype using protobuf compiler. This is neat, but I would also need to be able to serialize **existing structs**. I can't seem to find any info (but maybe I'm overlooking it).  Do you know if it is possible to serialize a struct in C++ using protobufs, so it can be read in .NET, without modifying said existing struct?

Comment: No it's not possible, you'll have to map the data.

Comment: That sucks. Can you suggest any alternative system?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nothing is impossible. Not in C++. Protobuf have a very simple encoding format and are made to be easy to deal with. Writing code to serialize into that format is quite easy, but it's inverting the classic protobuf work-flow that is hard (normal work-flow: write .proto message, generate C++ struct for it; inverse work-flow: write C++ struct with serialization routine, generate .proto message / prototype). But again, not impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

It's possible. In fact, I have done it. Not the .NET loading part, but the serialization to protobuf and the generation of a prototype from a C++ class. However, doing so requires a number of things and is not that easy.

First of all, protobufs are quite limited in their ability to represent data. They are basically only capable of representing POD-types (in the C++ sense), and very little else. I personally had to add a few basic things to the format to make it into a proper full-featured serialization format. But if you restrict yourself to POD-types, then the plain protobuf format will work fine.

The second thing is that you'll need a serialization library of some kind, and that will require that you add some code for each struct / class to perform the serialization / de-serialization (not necessarily "intrusively", meaning that you might not have to change the classes, just add some code on the side). You can look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), that's the basic template for how to create a serialization library in C++. Boost.Serialization is not particularly flexible for this purpose, and so, you might have to change a few things (like I had to do).

The third thing is that you will need quite a bit of wizardry under-the-hood to make this happen. In particular, you are going to need a reliable and feature-rich run-time type identification system (RTTI) in order to able to have useful type names, and you might need to clever meta-programming or some intrusive class hierarchy to be able to detect user-defined types for which you need to generate a prototype.

So, that's why my answer is "yes and no" because it is possible, but not without quite a bit of work and a good framework to rely on.

N.B.: Writing code to encode/decode data into the proto-buf format (with those small-ints, and all that) is really the easy part, proto-buf format is so simple, it's almost laughable. Writing the serialization framework that will allow you to do fancy things like generating prototypes, that's the hard part.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. I think it would be simpler to map the data to a generated message since there are a reasonably limited number of structs I'm working with but thanks so much for the detailed answer. I'm sure it'll come in handy in the future!

Comment: @Ben Yes, it is probably easier to just use the normal proto-buf workflow. The only reason I went through the trouble of doing what I described is because I already had all the mechanics (serialization / RTTI) in place, and it was a trivial matter to just implement the encoding and the generation of prototypes (.proto files). But without those mechanics in place, it's probably not worth the effort.